# Incorrect mathematical results calculating power series

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std ;

int main ()           
    {
        int n, sum=0 ;

        cout<< "Input number of terms: " ;
        cin>> n ;

        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            int k = pow(10, i) - 1 ;

            cout << k ;

            if(i < n)
            {
                cout<< " + " ;
            }


            sum += k ;
        }

        cout << "\nThe sum of the series = " << sum ;

        {int m;cin>>m;}
        return 0 ;
    }
```

every time I run this code it gives me weird  output like

```
9 + 98 + 999 + 9998 + ...
```

*it subtracts some Ks from 2 !!*

The rule is mathematically right and there is no syntax errors.

Is it the way of declaring k inside the loop or it's an compiler error ?

**So, what's wrong here?**

Comment: What are the expected results?

Comment: BTW, the `pow` function returns floating point.  You may experience rounding errors when converting from floating point to integer.

Comment: `rint()` would be a better way to convert floating point to integer, since it will round to the nearest integer rather than truncating the fractional part.  But even better than that would be to write your own `int ipow(int base, int exponent)` function that avoids floating-point math (and all of its gotchas) entirely.

Comment: IMHO, a more accurate version is to have a temporary variable that contains the power of 10.  In each loop, multiply the power variable by 10.  A lot simpler and more efficient than calling the `pow` function.

Comment: Regarding *This Code Doesn't Give The Expected Results*, would you be asking a question if it did?

Comment: @user4581301 why would !?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks it worked <3

rookie mistake

Comment: @JeremyFriesner ``` 9 + 99 + 999 + ...```

Comment: OK. That was me being too oblique. Apologies. The point is was trying to make is the question title contains no information.

Comment: @user4581301 it's ok dude,forgive me it's my first question ever so it's not that good

Comment: Downvote for stupid title. That would apply to every question on this site. The title is supposed to indicate the topic so as to attract the right readers.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne sry it's my first time to ask here, you can just down vote or reb me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `for` loop without using the `pow` function:

```
int power = 10;
for (int i = 1; i < n-1; ++i)
{
  const int k = power - 1 ;
  cout << k;
  if(i < n)
  {
    cout<< " + " ;
  }
  sum += k;
  power *= 10;  // This is important.
}
```

This should be more accurate than using `pow` because there is no conversions between integer and floating point.

Also, you may want to try using the series from 0 .. (n-1).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do is to create your own power function because pow() is not working that way before when I used it. Kinda like this one

```
int pow_num(int base_num, int exp_num) 
{

    int result = 1;

    for(int i = 0; exp_num > i; ++i)
    {
        result = result * base_num;
    }

    return (result); 
}
```